# Implementing Kenect and Google Analytics/Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

A client is requesting we track text conversions from Kenect in Google Analytics on their Wordpress website.

We are currently using Tag Manager on their site.

They sent over this code from Kenect - but we have no idea how we should be going about implementing this.

Has anyone does this before?

Below is what we were sent from the client.

```
An example implementation of how you might implement it with Google Analytics would
be as follows:

JavaScript
1 <script>
2 window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
3 const eventType = event && event.data && event.data.type
4 switch(eventType) {
5 case 'EVENT_SEND_MESSAGE':
6 ga('send', {
7 hitType: 'event',
8 eventCategory: 'KenectWidget',
9 eventAction: 'send_message'
10 });
11 break
12 case 'EVENT_WIDGET_OPENED':
13 ga('send', {
14 hitType: 'event',
15 eventCategory: 'KenectWidget',
16 eventAction: 'widget_opened'
17 });
18 break
19 default:
20 break
21 }
22 })
23 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Kenect is something that is meant to be embedded in a site via an iframe.

You typically can't do much to an iframe from the parent window, where GTM is deployed. Therefore, anything that happens in an iframe is invisible for GTM. That is unless the iframe explicitly sends window messages to the parent to indicate key events that happen in it.

What Kenect did there is they indicated there that they let you track two events that happen in their iframe: the widget opening and the message sending.

They store the indicator of the event in `event.data.type` of the window. That's not too many events, to be honest, but maybe they have more documented elsewhere and they mean it as just an example.

With this code, they directly send ga events with the ga() function, but you can rewrite that to switch it to dataLayer pushes and have normal GTM tags sending these events.

A professional thing to do would be:

1. Ask Kenect for the whole list of events they issue to the parent
2. Make a tag that would deploy the listener on real pageview that would translate window events to DL pushes, passing the `event.data.type` value
3. Make a Kenect-related lookup table in GTM that would map their event names to readable actions/labels
4. Make another tag that now would be triggered by the Kennect DL event that you send from the tag that we made in 2.
5. Fill our tag from 4 with the values from the LUT from 3 as you see fit.

Done. Pretty simple, comfortable to manage, elegant and compact implementation.

Note that there are many ways to implement things in GTM, but deploying an event listener is, unfortunately, a must in GTM. Unlike other TMSes, GTM doesn't have a native JS event trigger, so a good practice for now is to translate JS events into DL events manually.

Answer (score 0):

This works for sending Kenect events to GA4 from GTM (Google Tag Manager).

Specifically you need to build a Tag and a Trigger.

## trigger setup

1. Create trigger
2. Name it cHTML – all Pages
3. Set Trigger Type to Page view

## tag setup

1. Create a Custom HTML tag named cHTML – event listener and paste the code  in.
2. Set the trigger to cHTML – all Pages.
3. The GA4 Conversion Event: EVENT_SEND_MESSAGE

```
<script>
// Replace 'https://trusted-origin.com' with the 
// actual origin you expect to receive messages from.  
// no trailing slash is needed
var trustedOrigin = ['https://trusted-origin.com','https://storage.googleapis.com'];

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    console.log(event)
    if (trustedOrigin.indexOf(event.origin) > -1) {
        var messageType = event.data && event.data.type;
        var validMessageTypes = [
            'EVENT_SEND_MESSAGE',
            'EVENT_WIDGET_OPENED',
            'EVENT_WIDGET_CLOSED',
            'EVENT_LOCATION_SELECTED',
            'EVENT_DEPARTMENT_SELECTED',
            'EVENT_PROMPT_CLOSED',
            'EVENT_WIDGET_ERROR'
        ];
        if (validMessageTypes.indexOf(messageType) > -1) {
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            window.dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'GA4_event', 
                'GA4_eventName': messageType, 
                'event_properties': event.data.properties 
                });
        }
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
});
</script>
```